# Solved - Magento 2 - Get Products by Attribute Set

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

I'm looking for a way to get all products that belong to a certain attribute set, say 'Gloves'. I have look around online to see if I could find a way but could only find the code below which I believe is for Magento 1 because I'm getting a 500 error code. Also it is a .phtml template where I'm trying to get this data.

This is the code I have tried:

```
<?php
//Fetch attribute set id by attribute set name
$attrSetName = 'Gloves';
$attributeSetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->load($attrSetName, 'Helmets')
    ->getAttributeSetId();

//Load product model collecttion filtered by attribute set id
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

//process your product collection as per your bussiness logic
$productsName = array();
foreach($products as $p){
    $productsName[] = $p->getData('name');
}
?>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check this quick code, and try to optimize it as you wish,

```
$objectManager=   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$attrSetName = 'Default';
$attribute_set_factoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory');

$attribute_set_collection = $attribute_set_factoryCollection->create();

$attribute_set_collection
->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id',4)
->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name',$attrSetName);

$att_set = current($attribute_set_collection->getData());
$attribute_set_id = $att_set["attribute_set_id"];


$factoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $factoryCollection->create();
$collection->addFieldToSelect("name");
$collection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attribute_set_id);

$productsName = array();
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $productsName[] =  $item->getName();
}
print_r($productsName);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you soo much :)

Comment: I am glad to hear this, you are welcome

Comment: its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer uses `ObjectManager` directly, which is discouraged. A newer approach to retrieving model instances uses repositories. Here is an example how you could make use of it for your scenario:

```
class GetProductNamesByAttributeSetName
{
    private $criteriaBuilder;
    private $attributeSets;
    private $products;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->criteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->attributeSets = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->products = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function execute($name)
    {
        $setId = $this->getAttributeSetIdByName($name);
        if (empty($setId)) {
            return [];
        }

        return array_map(
            fn ($product) => $product->getName(),
            array_values($this->getProductsByAttributeSetId($setId))
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return int|null
     */
    private function getAttributeSetIdByName($name)
    {
        $criteria = $this->criteriaBuilder->addFilter(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::KEY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME, $name)->create();
        $sets = $this->attributeSets->getList($criteria)->getItems();
        return $sets? array_values($sets)[0]->getAttributeSetId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
     */
    private function getProductsByAttributeSetId($id)
    {
        $criteria = $this->criteriaBuilder->addFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID, $id)->create();
        return $this->products->getList($criteria)->getItems();
    }
}
```